# Stream Analytics and query and output

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am a learner of Azure Stream Analytics and now I met some issues that I cannot handle and want the help.

I write the query in Stream Analytics and the query pass the test (I upload a json file and run test, the result can output on the page).
And then I run the Stream Analytics job (output to the table), the intput is from the EventHub, however there are no contents output into table.

Then I made several tests and so far my conclusion is: 
When I write the query like this:

```
 SELECT * INTO [TABLE] FROM INTPUT
```

The results can render in table (all contents can output to the table).
However if I write the query like this:

```
SELECT ID, VALUE INTO [Table] FROM INTPUT
```

Nothing can ouput to table.

I am confused the reason. I hope someone can answer the question. Because my original query to handle the data is more complex (with join).

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between ID, Value and select * on the input side. Is your output and Azure table? If so, you have to at least select the columns that make up PartitionKey and rowKey. When you don't see output, please check operation logs, it usually has details about why there aren't any output. For the complex case, with joins etc. it is difficult to answer without additional details. Best course of action for you is to check input events metric, out of order policy, late events metric and operation logs.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, After I selected the partitionkey and rowkey I setted in output table, the query can ouput the results into table. And now I am investigating when it cannot ouput the results when I do the join operation.

Comment: You need to isolate the problem. Replace the table output with a blob output and ensure that you do get rows. If you do, the problem is in the target table. If you don't, it's the query. Even better, add *two* outputs, a blob *and* a table so you can check which rows didn't make it to the table